# How to define HTTP response as well as a ServiceBusMessage as result of an HttpTriggered Azure Function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I want to offload work to Azure Service Bus, when someone calls my Http Azure Function.  However, I also want to be able to define the actual `HttpResponseMessage` for that consumer. And obviously, I need to create the `ServiceBusMessage`.  And the way my function (based on documentation online) is now create, these have to be defined in the return object of my Function.

So I want to be able to create the Service Bus Message , but still also define the HTTP response message to my consumer.  Any idea/samples on how to do this?

```cs
[FunctionName(nameof(UserHistorySyncQueuedController))]
[return: ServiceBus(ServiceBusConstants.CommandTopicName, Connection = ServiceBusConstants.ConnectionString, EntityType = ServiceBusEntityType.Topic)]
public async Task<ServiceBusMessage> SynchronizeUserHistoryAsync(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "user/{userId}/syncq")]
    HttpRequestMessage req, string userId,
    ILogger log)
{
    // Validate request, and process from incoming Http request
    var request = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<UserSynchronizationRequest>();
    
    // Logic to validate if the incoming request is allowed and valid
    if (!_authorizer.Allowed(req, out var notAuthorizedResponse, userId))
    {
         // How can I return a HTTP 401 here ?
    }

    // obviously this message will contain body etc
    // but this message will be sent to the output binding 
    return new ServiceBusMessage(); 

    // But how can I define the http response here as well? 
}
```

Comment: How would you publish a bus message to Azure Service Bus from any old .NET app? You could do that. If you don't know how to do that, there's lots of documentation out there for you to give it a try.

Comment: I understand that, indeed. I just wanted to rely as much as possible on the available binding system and benefit from the actual abstraction there.  But if that won't be possible, I will indeed have to revert to leveraging a TopicClient